# (C#) to make file read/write thread-safe (and considering performance)

Tags: c#, thread-safety, file-handling

Here's my sample code, to make FileUtil class a thead-safe File IO handler.

```
public static class FileUtil {
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ReaderWriterLock> s_locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ReaderWriterLock>();

    public static string ReadFile(string path) {
        var rwLock = s_locks.GetOrAdd(path, new ReaderWriterLock());
        rwLock.AcquireReaderLock(1000);
        string data = File.ReadAllText(path);
        rwLock.ReleaseReaderLock();
        return data;
    }

    public static void WriteFile(string path, string data) {
        var rwLock = s_locks.GetOrAdd(path, new ReaderWriterLock());
        rwLock.AcquireWriterLock(1000);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true)) {
            sw.Write(data);             
        }
        rwLock.ReleaseWriterLock();
    }
}
```

As u see, i created a concurrent dicionary holding different locks for different files, to avoid all file IO using one lock. Is my implemetion correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, for few reasons.

First of all don't forget that **file system gives you the kind of concurrency you need** then you don't need to implement anything specifically. Note that thread-safe does not mean that resource can't be accessed concurrently but that its use won't result in a failure (in a very broad sense).

One possible implementation relying on OS for concurrency is:

```
public static string ReadFile(string path) {
    for (int retry=0; retry < 3; ++retry) {
        try {
            return File.ReadAllText(path);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // 0x80070020 is value for ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION
            if (Marshal.GetHRForException(e) == 0x80070020) {
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // Wait and try again
                continue;
            }

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for `WriteFile()` is straightforward.

Note that in this way you will also handle sharing violations between different processes and you will respect sharing rules declared when opening file; for example `File.WriteAllText()` specifies `FileShare.Read` allowing concurrent readings but disallowing concurrent writes, be careful because readers may then read a not up-to-date content and if it's not what you want then you should drop File.WriteAllText() to specify `FileShare.None` in `FileStream` constructor.

---

Few other notes about *general usage*.

You're using `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.GetOrAdd()` with an immediate value. It means that, even if dictionary already contains a `ReaderWriterLock` for given path, you will construct a new object each time. Lock isn't acquired during initialization but it's still an expensive operation then you should (in other code!) use the other overload:

```
var rwLock = s_locks.GetOrAdd(path, () => new ReaderWriterLock());
```

In this way `ReadWriterLock` will be created only if required.

Second point is `ReadWriterLock` itself, you may want to use `ReadWriterLockSlim` instead, it's a new lightweight resource-efficient version. You should also consider what to do when resource acquisition timeouts, throw an exception? Retry?

Last point is about usage: think after you used that code for 1000 files, your dictionary will contain 1000 (possibly unused) objects. In another scenario you may consider to dispose them after each usage.

Comment: Thank you Adriano Repetti. You are right. But for my dictionary-locking example, does it help for other thread-sensitive resource reader/writers ?

Comment: @ineztia yes, I added few notes about _general_ usage.